# My input field required option is not working

Tags: html, css, input, form-submit, required

The required option on my input field does not display when I click on the submit button.

This is a webpage which requires submitting button, but I will need that option to pop up when I click on the first button.

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="pay.png">
  <div class="txt">
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Email address or mobile number" required="required">
  </div>
  <div class="nxt">
    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="or">or</div>
  <div class="sign_up">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="">
  </div>
  <select>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>Uniited Kingdom</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
    <option>Ghana</option>
    <option>Liberia</option>
    <option>South Africa</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="links">`
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Wordwide</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Are your form elements within a form tag?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap logical input values inside a form to ensure that required attribute has any effect. Suppose the first input and next button are part of the same flow, use something like this(I am only adding the form tags) :

```
 <form>
...
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Email address or mobile number" required="required">
...
        <input type="submit" value="Next" name="">
...
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

'required', only works when the form is submitted.